# How to detect the real type of file at a URL?

Tags: java, android, file

Often a URL which has a .jpg extension can turn out to be a .gif or .mp4 type of file and vice versa. Is there a way to figure out exactly what type of file a URL contains without downloading the entire file?

Example: [http://i.imgur.com/9b4bIW9.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/9b4bIW9.jpg)

This has .jpg extension, but is actually a .gif.

Comment: Yay a 2 year old question with a solution just got marked as duplicate?? A bit too late dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: My solution requires:

```
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
```

as it provides the `ByteStreams.toByteArray` function to get the bytes array from an input stream. Of course you can use some other method to read the input stream.

NOTE: the `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy` stuff is required, else you will get exceptions.

Basically, we create a HTTP connection but only request first single byte of the remote url file. So we don't need to download the entire file.
Then pass the bytes array through the `bytestohex` function to get it as raw bytes. Finally compare the first byte's signature with your requirements which I got from this url:

For other file types and signatures of file bytes, you can refer to:
http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html

**Code:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    try {
        detectTypeOfFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("URL: CRASH: " + e.getStackTrace());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}

public void detectTypeOfFile() throws IOException {

    String[] urls = {"http://i.imgur.com/9b4bIW9.jpg","http://i.imgur.com/f00y2uz.jpg","http://i.imgur.com/9b4bIW9.mp4","http://i.imgur.com/9b4bIW9.gif"};

    for (int i=0;i<urls.length;i++){
        URL url = new URL(urls[i]);
        HttpURLConnection connection = ((HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection());
        connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes="+0+"-"+0);
        connection.connect();
        byte[] bytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(connection.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("URL: " + url.toString() + "  is of type: " + bytesToHex(bytes));
        switch (bytesToHex(bytes)) {
            //http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html
            case "00":
                System.out.println("URL: " + url.toString() + "  is of type: mp4");
                break;
            case "FF":
                System.out.println("URL: " + url.toString() + "  is of type: image/jpeg");
                break;
            case "89":
                System.out.println("URL: " + url.toString() + "  is of type: image/png");
                break;
            case "47":
                System.out.println("URL: " + url.toString() + "  is of type: image/gif");
                break;
            case "49":
            case "4D":
                System.out.println("URL: " + url.toString() + "  is of type: image/tiff");
                break;
        }
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

**Output from above:**

```
06-05 01:51:47.022 12554-12554/? I/System.out: URL: http://i.imgur.com/9b4bIW9.jpg  has first byte: 47
06-05 01:51:47.022 12554-12554/? I/System.out: URL: http://i.imgur.com/9b4bIW9.jpg  is of type: image/gif
06-05 01:51:47.056 12554-12554/? I/System.out: URL: http://i.imgur.com/f00y2uz.jpg  has first byte: FF
06-05 01:51:47.056 12554-12554/? I/System.out: URL: http://i.imgur.com/f00y2uz.jpg  is of type: image/jpeg
06-05 01:51:47.091 12554-12554/? I/System.out: URL: http://i.imgur.com/9b4bIW9.mp4  has first byte: 00
06-05 01:51:47.091 12554-12554/? I/System.out: URL: http://i.imgur.com/9b4bIW9.mp4  is of type: mp4
06-05 01:51:47.124 12554-12554/? I/System.out: URL: http://i.imgur.com/9b4bIW9.gif  has first byte: 47
06-05 01:51:47.124 12554-12554/? I/System.out: URL: http://i.imgur.com/9b4bIW9.gif  is of type: image/gif
```